# Web Audio API in UIWebView stops Music app's current song

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, web-audio-api

A simple usage of the Web Audio API:

```
var UnprefixedAudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var context;
var volumeNode;
var soundBuffer;

context = new UnprefixedAudioContext();
volumeNode = context.createGain();
volumeNode.connect(context.destination);
volumeNode.gain.value = 1;

context.decodeAudioData(base64ToArrayBuffer(getTapWarm()), function (decodedAudioData) {
    soundBuffer = decodedAudioData;
});

function play(buffer) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(volumeNode);
    (source.start || source.noteOn).call(source, 0);
};

function playClick() {
    play(soundBuffer);
}
```

inside a `UIWebView` works fine (plays the sound); but when you switch to the Music app and play a song, and then come back to the app with the `UIWebView` the song stops playing.

The same code inside Safari doesn't have this problem.

Is there a workaround to avoid this behavior?

Here's the full fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielmaldi/4Lvdyhpx/

Comment: This seems to be the way UIWebView is designed. There is not much WebAudio can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you on iOS? This sounds like an audio session category issue to me. iOS apps define how their audio interacts with audio. From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW1):

> Each audio session category specifies a particular pattern of “yes”
>   and “no” for each of the following behaviors, as detailed in Table
>   B-1:
>
> Interrupts non-mixable apps audio: If yes, non-mixable apps will be
>   interrupted when your app activates its audio session.
>
> Silenced by the Silent switch: If yes, your audio is silenced when the
>   user moves the Silent switch to silent. (On iPhone, this switch is
>   called the Ring/Silent switch.)
>
> Supports audio input: If yes, app audio input (recording), is allowed.
>
> Supports audio output: If yes, app audio output (playback), is
>   allowed.

Looks like the default category silences audio from other apps:

> AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient—(Default) Playback only. Silences
>   audio when the user switches the Ring/Silent switch to the “silent”
>   position and when the screen locks. This category differs from the
>   AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient category only in that it interrupts
>   other audio.

The key here is in the last sentence: "it interrupts other audio".

There are a number of other categories you can use depending on whether or not you want your audio silenced when the screen is locked, etc. `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` does not silence audio.

Give this a try in the objective-c portion of your app:

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;

BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient
                      error: &setCategoryError];

if (!success) { /* handle the error in setCategoryError */ }
```